# How to combine first element of cell array with all elements of another array and so on?

Tags: matlab

I have two (n,1) cell arrays. Both of those contain 1x8 cell arrays inside each cell.

I need to:

1) Combine the first element of the first array with each element of the second array

2) Combine the second element of the first array with each element of the second array and so on.

And then store them inside a third cell array that will look like this :

```
{ {f_array1} {s_array1}; {f_array1} {s_array2}; {f_arrayN} {s_array2}; {f_arrayM} {s_arrayM};
```

I have tried some for loops like this one:

```
for l = 1:u(1,1)
    for m = 1:v(1,1)
        A{l} = {e{l},f{m}};
    end
end
```

But in only combines the one element with only one element.

Any sugestions?

Comment: did you mean A{l,m} ?

Comment: No, only A{l}. Why?

Comment: could you give an example of your input and output?

Comment: Input is a cell array of size nx1 that contains inside each cell, some cell arrays with 1x8 elements. Output should be a cell array of size nx2, that will look like this: { {f_array1} {s_array1}; {f_array1} {s_array2}; {f_arrayN} {s_array2}; {f_arrayM} {s_arrayM};

Comment: I see. Well, good luck. I hope you solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `repmat` on the cell arrays to expand them out and then simply concatenate them.

```
f_array = {{{1} {1} {1} {1} {1} {1} {1} {1}},...
    {{2} {2} {2} {2} {2} {2} {2} {2}},...
    {{3} {3} {3} {3} {3} {3} {3} {3}}};
s_array = {{{4} {4} {4} {4} {4} {4} {4} {4}},...
    {{5} {5} {5} {5} {5} {5} {5} {5}},...
    {{6} {6} {6} {6} {6} {6} {6} {6}}};


f_expanded = repmat(f_array(:), numel(s_array), 1);
s_expanded = repmat(s_array(:), 1, numel(f_array)).';

output = num2cell(cat(2, f_expanded(:), s_expanded(:)), 2);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, it sorta worked. The problem is, it does not match the first with the second, third, four and so on. It only copies the second one N times the first one.

Comment: Actually, it correctly does the match but it matches each of the second array elements to three elements of the first one :(

Comment: @marco So what if you just flip which one I'm calling `f_array` and `s_array`?

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, It is indeed faster than for loops. You saved my life bro <3